# Is it possible to pass a function with arguments and then call it in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass a function which return type is a `Stream<Foo>` to a consumer, for reusability purposes. The reason I want to do this is because I want to close the stream on the class that I pass it when I am done with it.

If I send a `Stream<Foo>` directly I don't like the idea that I am closing it in a "child" object, and I might hold a reference and use it after `close()` is called on the class that created it.

```
// Declare some functions that return a Stream<Foo>
Stream<Foo> stream1() => GenerateStream();
Stream<Foo> stream2(String a) => GenerateStreamWith1Argument(a);
Stream<Foo> stream3(String a, int b) => GenerateStreamWith2Argument(a, b);

// Constructor
MyStreamConsumer(Stream<Foo> Function(...) f){ // Something like ... operator in Dart?
    Stream<Foo> stream = f.call(); // Now I can dispose Stream on this object since was created here.
}

// Instantiation
MyStreamConsumer(stream1());
MyStreamConsumer(stream2('SomeString'));
MyStreamConsumer(stream3('SomeString', 1));
```

Is this possible to accomplish? Or there is any alternative to solve this problem?

**Edit** (Why I don't want to pass the stream directly):

```
Stream<Foo> stream = stream1();
MyStreamConsumer(stream); // I might have used and disposed the stream which makes kinda undefined behavior.
stream.listen() // Here I am probably listening a closed stream.
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass a function that can have arguments passed to it, or are you trying to pass a function that has _specific_ arguments passed to it?

Comment: @Abion47 Sorry if the example has errors (Since stream1() returns a Stream<Foo> but I don't know the correct notation or if its possible). My idea was to pass a function that can be called later with the arguments that I have specified early like on the instantion comment.

Comment: If you call a function with specific arguments, assuming it's a pure function, you will always get the same object back. So why pass the function and not just pass the stream itself?

Comment: @Abion47 I made an edit trying to explain why.

Comment: Then what you need is a factory object. Initialize the factory with the parameters you want to pass, then you can recreate the stream with those parameters whenever you want.